# Node.js chaining promises in a loop with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, loops, promise

I am trying to make a non-relational DB into a relational DB. So I am starting from data with no unique IDs.

I need to get the result from one SQL call loop through those rows, and for each one, do a SQL SELECT using part of the first result, then another SQL select using the next result, and then a write using IDs from the first and last queries.

I am using Node.js and ES6 promises to keep everything in order, but I seem to be missing something. I was actually trying to do an extra SQL call, and also use that result in the third query, but I am simplifying it to just get one call to feed into another.

Maybe some code will help show what I am trying to do.

Here is my query class that returns promises:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            password: "root",
            database: "pressfile"
        }); 
    }

    query(sql, args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.query(sql, args, (err, result, fields) => {
                if (err) return reject(err);

                resolve (result);
            });
        });
    }

    close() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.end(err => {
                if (err) return reject (err);

                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This was stolen pretty much as is from a tutorial site, and this part seems to work pretty well. Then here comes the loop, and the multiple queries:

```
var contactId;
var address1;
var orgName;

var database = new Database();

database.query("SELECT * FROM contact")
    .then( result => {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            contactId = result[i].contactId;
            orgName = result[i].org;

            var sql2 = "SELECT * FROM organization WHERE (name = \"" + orgName + "\")";
            console.log(sql2);

            database.query(sql2)
            .then(result2 => {
                console.log(result2);

                var orgId = result2[0].organizationId;
                var sql3 = "INSERT INTO contact_organization (contactId, organizationId) VALUES (" + contactId + ", " + orgId + ")";
                console.log(sql3);

                return ""; //database.query(sql3);
            }).then( result3 => {
                console.log(result3);
            });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        databse.close();
    });
```

I know it is kind of unraveling at the end, but I'm not wanting to do the INSERT query until I know I can get it right. Right now in the console, I get a valid organization object, followed by:

```
`INSERT INTO contact_organization (contactId, organizationId) VALUES (17848, 29)'
```

17848 is the final contactId that is returned in the for loop. How can I get the contactId that is assigned before the second query. I know I am not doing this asynchronous stuff right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, but it is kind of cheesy. I included the contactId as a constant in the SQL query to get the organization, so I could then pass the value to the .then, keeping everything in order.

My sql2 statement becomes:

```
var sql2 = "SELECT *, " + contactId + " AS contactId FROM organization WHERE (name = \"" + orgName + "\")";
```

Then when that query returns, I can just pull the correct contactId out as result[0].contactId, from the same result I get the organizationId from.

Here is the final code:

```
database.query("SELECT * FROM contact")
    .then( result => {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var contactId = result[i].contactId;
            var orgName = result[i].org;

            var sql2 = "SELECT *, " + contactId + " AS contactId FROM organization WHERE (name = \"" + orgName + "\")";

            database.query(sql2)
            .then(result2 => {
                var orgId = result2[0].organizationId;
                var contactId = result2[0].contactId;

                var sql3 = "INSERT INTO contact_organization (contactId, organizationId) VALUES (" + contactId + ", " + orgId + ")";
                console.log(sql3);

                return database.query(sql3);
            }).then( result3 => {
                console.log(result3);
            });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        databse.close();
    });
```

The console.log(result3) returns a bunch of these:

```
OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }
```

And I got one contact_organization inserted for every contact row returned from the first query.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Just a quick solution. (not tested).

```
const selectOrg = (result) => {
  contactId = result[i].contactId;
  orgName = result[i].org;
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM organization WHERE (name = \"" + orgName + "\")";

  return database.query(sql);
};

const insertOrg = (result) => {
  var orgId = result[0].organizationId;
  var sql = "INSERT INTO contact_organization (contactId, organizationId) VALUES (" + contactId + ", " + orgId + ")";
  return database.query(sql);
};

database.query("SELECT * FROM contact")
  .then(result => {
    const promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      promises << selectOrg(result)
        .then(insertOrg);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .then(allResults => {
    console.log(allResults);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    databse.close();
  });
```

Comment: I had to clean it up some, for instance result[i] should be inside the for loop, not in the selectOrg promise. At that point all we need is 'result'. However, I am still getting all organizations linked to the same contactId, 17848, which is the last contactId looped through.

Comment: Your code was not bad, though. I was able to get it to run pretty quickly. But it does still produce the same result as the original code above.

Comment: @ScottM I didn't read your question properly. I don't understand `How can I get the contactId that is assigned before the second query` Can you explain ?

Comment: At the beginning of the for loop, right after the return from the 'SELECT * FROM contacts' query, it assigns contactId = result[i].contactId. This is the contactId I want, at that point. But the asynchronous code is going through all of those queries before it starts to build the 'INSERT INTO contact_organization'... etc. query.

Comment: I have figured out a kind of hacky way to pass the value through to the final insert query, and I'm writing it up as an answer now.